# Eclipse JSHint plugin installed but not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jshint

I use 2018-09 (4.9) x86 and have downloaded 0.10.1 through Eclipse Marketplace.
It is present in both list of installed software and p2 -> pool -> plugins folder but not appears in Project -> Properties menu.
I did cache clear and restart - no luck. Any tips?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit and not a 64-bit operating system, or why do you spend your time doing retrocomputing instead of using Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24) with [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper)?

Comment: You could try looking in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. But all this is very old.

Comment: My PC is operated by Win 7 32-bit so its the latest version I can use. In log file there's nothing about JSHint mentioned unfortunately. Maybe I should place some plugin files manually at some Eclipse folders too?

Comment: Are you sure this is part of its feature set?

Comment: I see. For security reasons you should upgrade you Win 7. What kind of project you are talking? Is it a JavaScript project?

Comment: Sprign Boot project with Thymeleaf + JQuery pages - not in much quantity but searching typos with eyes is a bit annoying.

Comment: And when you create a JavaScript project and copy or link these JavaScript file into the JavaScript project? Note, Eclipse Wild Web Developer would not require that.

Comment: For new JavaScript project its also not appear. I've added some screen-shots about installation.

Comment: There are a couple of things that are weird here: _Installation Details_ dialog showing only one root feature; the _Plug-ins_ showing plugins of Eclipse WST instead of EclipseSource; the _Target Definition_ dialog which does not make sense here. Maybe you messed your Eclipse installation. I'm only aware about the [EclipseSource JSHint plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jshint-eclipse), but maybe there are more JSHint plugins and it is unclear which one you have.

Comment: Its definitely this one You've mentioned by link - no other plugins for Eclipse with the name "JSHint" exist. I did reinstall JSHint but nothing changes. Probably something's wrong with Eclipse installation itself. Thanks for attempts to help anyway!